# Red dot and red lines using the linter pylama with the text editor Atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am using the text editor Atom and the linter Pylama. I see red dots on the left of the screen as well as red hashed lines on certain lines of code. I do not see any corresponding errors displayed in the Atom console below. What do the red dots and red hashed lines indicate?

[image]

Comment: Try hovering over the lines, it should display the error message.

Comment: It does not seem to pop up anything. Sometimes it will do that. and other times it won't

Comment: Wild guess: bad indentation?

Comment: i dont think that is it? at least its not throwing errors saying that on those line numbers. Where are u seeing the bad indents?

Answer (score 0):

Your must have installed the package named "linter" ,
on your atom editor type ctrl+comma , click on install and search for 'linter' and disable it .

Answer (score 0):

I had it next to various lines implementing different calls e.g. starting a for-loop, or plt.plot statement etc. I literally just pushed the line down one and brought it back back up (Enter and then backspace) and the dots went away. Guess its kind of like 'clearing the cache'.